# Java class that inherits either class or its subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have a base `class A` that provides some functionality and a subclass `B extends A` that provides additional functionality on top of `A`.

Assuming classes `C`, `D`, and `E` extend `A`, how would I construct classes of `C`, `D`, and `E` that extend `B` instead (without making new classes that basically duplicate `C`, `D`, and `E`)?

Classes `C`, `D`, and `E` that extend `A` are still needed in addition to those that extend `B`.

For example (feel free to improve it):

```
A = Ball - provides basic things that are shared by all balls
B = Beach ball - provides some beach ball specific things
C has a method roll() that could allow A or B to roll
D has a method bounce() that could allow A or B to bounce
E has a method spin() that could allow A or B to spin

Any ball can have all, some, or none of the features C, D, and E
```

The goal is to be able to create objects of type `A` or `B` that include features from the set `{C, D, E}` without having to make classes for all possible combinations

Comment: Extend directly class B it will automatically extend class A. As Class B is subclass of Class A

Comment: Whether C,D,E all the three extends A right now?

Comment: Yes, sorry if the wording is ambiguous, C,D,E all extend A and I need it to be able to extend A without extending B (features of A+C, A+D, A+E).  I also want C,D,E to be able to extend B as well (so, features A+B+C, A+B+D, A+B+E)

Comment: Perhaps I'm approaching it incorrectly.  Suppose C, D, and E each add a feature to A and I want it to be able to extend its subclasses as well

Comment: As far as i know java has a single level hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, a class can only extend *one* class. If you want implementations of C, D and E that extend B instead of A, you must create new classes.

But, behaviour can be controlled in ways *other* that class hierarchy.

One option would be to use the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), in combination with interfaces:

```
interface MyInterface {
    public void someMethod();
}
class A implements MyInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something different
    }
}

class C implements MyInterface {
    private final MyIntegerface delegate;
    public C(MyIntegerface delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public void someMethod() {
        delegate.someMethod(); 
    }
}
```

The client constructing the C object passes to it the delegate the client wants C to use:

```
C x = new C(new A());
C y = new C(new B());
```

There's only one definition of class C, but multiple ways it can behave.

Comment: Looking pretty good! However, if `B` also has a `public void someOtherMethod()`, can that still be used by `y`?

Comment: That's the idea. If you don't want it to be used, pass in an instance of A

Comment: So how do I specify `public void someOtherMethod()` is available on instances of `C` when is constructed from a `B`?  Is it specified in the interface? (but then `A` would need to implement/stub it?)

Comment: C either (always) has `someOtherMethod()` or does not - all the time in all circumstances. That's the nature of the definition of a class. If what you want is dynamic classes, java is not the language for you.

Answer (score 0):

If Class B extends A. Then you can make Classes (C,D and E) extends class B instead of A. By this the three classes (C, D and E) can use the public functionality(attributes and methods) available in both classes B and A (inheritance hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

Class B extends Class A. So all functionality of Class A will be inherited in Class B.

```
Class B extends A{}
```

Now you want Class C, D, E to extend functionality of Class A and B Which can be done by simply extending Class B instead of Class A

```
Class C extends B{}
Class D extends B{}
Class E extends B{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend class B directly instead of class A. you can understand better if you look into [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Add Basic functionalities of Ball Like roll(), bounce() and spin() in Ball Class as all Balls should have these three. And Extend Class A in Class B so by doing this you can instantiate Ball and Beach Ball where Ball and Beach Ball both will be having roll bounce and Spin and Beach Ball would be having its own features

Comment: Yes, but then you can't create items of A (not B) that include features of self (being C, D, or E)

Comment: Dear @arcyqwerty , As you have changed your question. In your question the query and the example are contradictory. the example you have given could be implemented in Java by creating interfaces C,D and E , and Implementing them on A and B as you want to create Objects of A and B at the End

Comment: Interfaces can't have implementations right? So for each time I'd implement it, I'd have to copy the implementation (since it's not inherited)?  And yes, apologies for changing the question.  I don't think I was very clear with what I had originally said vs what I was looking for.

Comment: Apart from the above if you want to create the representation you quoted in your question rather using inheritence you can have Objects of Class C,D and E inside A and B or you can have Objects of Class A and B inside Class C,D and E depends what you want to initialize as a Object

Comment: First of All Classes C,D and E are the classes which are providing features so they should be the Base Classes not the Classes you instantiate. the classes you will instantiate are A and B Ball and Beach Ball. I am Editing the Answer as per your need please check

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

```
abstract class Ball {

< some common functionality >

}
```

Now BeachBall is a concrete class, it is a specific ball. So you should take it as a separated class, now

```
:

   class BeachBall extends Ball {

   < some common functionality inherited from Ball >
   <additional functionality>

   }
```

Other classes like C,D,E also is concrete classes and assume it is another type of balls, so :

```
   class C extends Ball {

   < some common functionality inherited from C >
   <additional C funcionality>

   }

   <other classes are ommited>
```

Or if your C,E,D classes are more specific type of BeachBall, it can be done like this:

```
  class C extends BeachBall {

   < some common functionality inherited from BeachBall & Ball >
   <additional C funcionality>

   }

   <other classes are ommited>
```

**N.B** `<other classes are ommited>` means the same applies to E,D same as C.